# Chaining Multiple Query Filters in Vapor - Server Side Swift

Tags: swift, vapor, server-side-swift

We can apply a simple query filter in vapor with:

```
// User is my model object connecting corresponding MySQL database table
let aUser = try User.query().filter("user_email", "asd@example.com")
```

How can we chain multiple query filters with AND or OR conditions like we do in SQL queries?

Say for example, if we need to join `filter("user_email", "asd@example.com")` and `filter("user_password", "123456")` with an `AND` condition, how can we achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know the .filter function throws a bool after checking the condition to filter. So you can try to combine two conditions with the logical AND-operator. For a proper solution it would be good to know the structure and properties of your object User: but a suggestion would be:

```
    let aUser = User.query().filter { condition1 && condition2 }
```

Filter would only pass an element of User.query() to aUser, if BOTH conditions are true. Make sure, that User.query() is an array and that you refer to the current object with $0 in your conditions. The filter function will also return an Array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Procra. I'll try it out this and come back.

Comment: By the way which version of swift do you use? I'm currently on swift 3, where some of the old well-known objective-c patterns are deprecated, so it may be, that the syntax of .filter can be a little bit different.

Comment: I'm with 3.0.1 :)

Comment: Then it should work to filter with more conditions by writing them in curly brackets B)